# Why does putting Eliminate in ContourPlot not plot anything?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'm having an issue with my code. I will be trying to eliminate variables from a system of simultaneous equations and just trying to plot 2 of them. In the simplest example, I am hoping the following will plot the line $y = x$:

`ContourPlot[Eliminate[{x == z, z == y}, z], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]`

But it just returns the blank square. What is the syntax for actually plotting the correct $x, y$ points that solve the equation?

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  Try `Eliminate[{x == z, z == y}, z]` which gives `y = x`, which is certainly not in any form appropriate for `ContourPlot`.

Comment: `ContourPlot[
 Eliminate[{x == z, z == y}, z] // Evaluate, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]`

Comment: `ContourPlot` holds the code (does not let it evaluate) and inspects the `Head[]` of the code to determine what sort of contour plot will be constructed. The `Head` in your case is `Eliminate`, and it does not know what to do with it. Hence, @cvgmt's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
With[{e = Eliminate[{x == z, z == y}, z]}, 
 ContourPlot[e, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]]
```

Evaluating `Trace[ContourPlot[Eliminate[{x == z, z == y}, z], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]]` (output not shown here because it is large) shows that the `Eliminate` does not get evaluated inside `ContourPlot`.

Meanwhile, `Trace[With[{e = Eliminate[{x == z, z == y}, z]},  ContourPlot[e, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]]]` shows that `e` gets set to the result of `Eliminate[{x == z, z == y}, z]` early on in the computation.